# Python scraping a tag in div,dl tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm making movie expert's review scraper. And I made this code with Jupiter Notebook.
And I want to scrape this part. [image: movie expert's name]

I tried

```
soup.find('div', 'reporter_line')
```

and

```
soup.find('dl','p_review')
```

but it doesn't work.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

How do I fix this code to scraping this text?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import urljoin
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re

#url_base = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/pointWriteFormList.nhn?code=25917&type=after&page=1'
base_url = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/basic.nhn?code=' #movie title
pages =['158191','47384','52745','91391','179482','38466','141259','182205','56447',
        '86023','88426','66025','130903','120157','132998','97693','121051','158112',
        '93728','99752','37247','37838','105249','61698','73476','49480','34210',
        '74893','113312','122133','35937','114139','134772','88253','37919','45914',
        '144314','75413','171755','37262','35938','116532','68435','154449',
        '41585','47701','34570','145162','157297','179461','42809','104467','144578','66002',
        '142625','137952','86888','64950','180402','164151','134895','52545','130966','129050',
        '79557','50932','164173','70276','44456','129051','74522','122984','37929',
        '124025','167697','85579','38452','146459','45232','76016','123519','46532','163533',
        '146544','174903','63537','25917','108225','164102','136686','93028','63061',
        '54411','161984','106522','53158','179158','88295','52548','52498','109906','39379',
        '48227','130786','177374','69270','34324','124041','38888','34197','73344',
        '125805','118922','81891','35939','31606','67769','130720','136007','34190','99724',
        '120165','62727','48742','98149','142803','39715','30791','36019','159805']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for n in pages:
    # Create url
    url = base_url + n
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find('h3', 'h_movie')
    for a in title.find_all('a'):
                    #print(a.text)
                    title=a.text
    rname = soup.find('div','reporter_line')
    for a in rname.find_all(('a')['href']):
                    #print(a.text)
                    rname=a.text
    rreview = soup.find('p','tx_report')   
    data = {'title':[title],'rname':[rname], 'rreview':[rreview]}

df.to_csv('./reviewr.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: if i remember correctly beautiful soup find use the following parameters `find('dl', attrs={'class': 'p_review'})` [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

Comment: `title` or `rname` are None and therefore  you get 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all''. Before you call find_all make sure rname/title  are not None

Comment: I tried as you suggested but it didn't work. There are no errors but it wasn't saved rname in csv file.

Comment: I tried to open the urls but there're no `dl`or element with `p_review` class or `reporter_line`.

Answer (score 0):

title or rname are None and therefore you get 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'.
Try this for to pull out 'reporter_line'

```
soup.find('div', {'class' : 'reporter_line'})
```

If the title tag(h3) also has 'h_movie' as class then,

```
soup.find('div', {'class' : 'h_movie'})
```

Or if the 'h_movie' is an 'id', use :

```
soup.find(id='h_movie')
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: title=soup.find('div', {'class' : 'reporter_line'})